# How to add multiple value to a multipicklist from apex

Tags: apex, multi-select

I am trying to add multiple value to a multipicklist from apex. I put the value into a list of string and added it don't allow to add, try to add using a string split by ',' but it get added as a single record try to add one by one in this case only the last record get saved. How can i achieve it. Please help me to get the solution.

```
List<String> picklistValues = new List<String>();
String selected;
picklistValues  = itemChoiceSetconfigItemCodeMap.get(configItemsID);
for(String picklistValue : picklistValues){
   // Add pick list values
   configItem.Chose_Code__c = picklistValue;
}
//configItem.Chose_Code__c = picklistValues  ;
```

Please guide me a best way to do this.

Answer (score 16):

These are methods I use for this purpose:

```
public static String format(Set<String> values) {
    if (values == null) return null;
    List<String> l = new List<String>(values);
    l.sort();
    return format(l);
}

public static String format(List<String> values) {
    if (values == null) return null;
    return String.join(values, ';');
}
```

so in your case:

```
configItem.Chose_Code__c = format(picklistValues);
```

Answer (score 15):

Multi-select picklist values are stored as a semicolon separated string.

Thus to set a value via Apex containing options 'a', 'b and 'c', you'd have something like:

```
configItem.Chose_Code__c = 'a;b;c';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add values in a picklist like the following example.

```
Public String SelectedOppr {set; get;}
 Public List<SelectOption> getOpprortunities(){
      list<SelectOption> OpprList = new list<SelectOption>();     
      for( Opportunity o: childList){ //childList contains the records 
        OpprList.Add(New SelectOption(o.Id,o.Name));     
      }
      return OpprList;
    }
```

In vf page, you can use this as :

```
 <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedOppr}" size="5" multiselect="true">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!Opprortunities}" >
              </apex:selectOptions>
        </apex:selectList>
```

Let me know if this helps.