# 3 dependent Multi-Select PickList - display detail record and edit record

Tags: apex, visualforce, multi-select, dependent-picklist

I have VF page with 3 multi-select picklists and dependents.

"Multi Indication Level 1" is controlling multi-select picklist. "Multi Indication Level 2" is dependent on "Multi Indication Level 2". "Multi Indication Level 3" dependent on "Multi Indication Level 3".

So far, I am able to enter data on the page and select picklist values and save the record. Working very fine.

To display an existing record or edit the record, I want to display selected picklist values on these fields - "Multi Indication Level 1", 2 and 3.

If I assign one value it is working, the value displayed as selected.
MultiPickListIndicationLevel1 = 'Blood';

If assign 2 values, it is not displaying as selected. I've tried both:

`MultiPickListIndicationLevel1 = 'Blood, Cancer';`

`MultiPickListIndicationLevel1 = 'Blood; Cancer';`

Below is the code snippet of VF page and controller.

## Visualforce

```
<apex:selectList id="MIL1" value="{!MultiPickListIndicationLevel1}" Label="Multi Indication Level 1" multiselect="true" size="5">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!MultiIndicationLevel1}"/>    
        <apex:actionSupport rerender="MIL2, MIL3" event="onchange"/>
</apex:selectList>

<apex:selectList id="MIL2" value="{!MultiPickListIndicationLevel2}" Label="Multi Indication Level 2" multiselect="true" size="5">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!MultiIndicationLevel2}"/>   
        <apex:actionSupport rerender="MIL3" event="onchange"/>
</apex:selectList>    

<apex:selectList id="MIL3" value="{!MultiPickListIndicationLevel3}" Label="Multi Indication Level 3" multiselect="true" size="5">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!MultiIndicationLevel3}"/>   
</apex:selectList>
```

## Controller

```
public string MultiPickListIndicationLevel1{get; set;}
public string MultiPickListIndicationLevel2{get; set;}
public string MultiPickListIndicationLevel3{get; set;}


public List<SelectOption> getMultiIndicationLevel1(){
    system.debug('Inside getMultiIndicationLevel1');
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('UnKnown','--UnKnown--'));
    system.debug('inside IndLeve1and2.keySet(): ' + IndLeve1and2.keySet());
    for(string IndLevel1 : new List<string>(IndLeve1and2.keySet()))
    {
        system.debug('inside IndLevel1' + IndLevel1);
        if(IndLevel1 <> null && IndLevel1 <> '')
            options.add(new SelectOption(IndLevel1, IndLevel1));
    }    
    system.debug('inside options: ' + options);
    return options;
}

public List<SelectOption> getMultiIndicationLevel2(){

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    if(MultiPickListIndicationLevel1 == null || MultiPickListIndicationLevel1 == '[UnKnown]')
    {    
        options = null;
        return options;
    }        
    options.add(new SelectOption('UnKnown','--UnKnown--'));
    List<string> selectedPLvalues = MultiPickListIndicationLevel1.substring(1, MultiPickListIndicationLevel1.length()-1).split(', ');
    for(string selectedPLValue : selectedPLvalues)
    {
        if(IndLeve1and2.get(selectedPLValue) <> null)
        {    
            for(string DependPL : IndLeve1and2.get(selectedPLValue))
            {
                options.add(new SelectOption(DependPL, DependPL));
            }
        }    

    }    

    return options;             
}

public List<SelectOption> getMultiIndicationLevel3(){

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    if(MultiPickListIndicationLevel2 == '[]' || MultiPickListIndicationLevel2 == null  || MultiPickListIndicationLevel2 == '[UnKnown]'
      || MultiPickListIndicationLevel1 == '[UnKnown]' || 
       (MultiPickListIndicationLevel1 <> MultiPickListIndicationLevel1OLDVAL && MultiPickListIndicationLevel1 <> null))
    {    
        options = null;
        MultiPickListIndicationLevel1OLDVAL = MultiPickListIndicationLevel1; 
        return options;
    }

    MultiPickListIndicationLevel1OLDVAL = MultiPickListIndicationLevel1;            
    options.add(new SelectOption('UnKnown','--UnKnown--'));
    List<string> selectedPLvalues = MultiPickListIndicationLevel2.substring(1, MultiPickListIndicationLevel2.length()-1).split(', ');

    for(string selectedPLValue : selectedPLvalues)
    {
        if(IndLeve2and3.get(selectedPLValue) <> null)
        {    
            for(string DependPL : IndLeve2and3.get(selectedPLValue))
            {
                options.add(new SelectOption(DependPL, DependPL));
            }
        }    

    }    
    return options;             


}
```

**Questions Answers:**
Expected Pickist values for MultiPickListIndicationLevel1 are  "Blood" "Cancer".
I tried assigning value to variable MultiPickListIndicationLevel1 in controller.
It is not working.

Comment: see a related question [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79545/how-to-add-multiple-value-to-a-multipicklist-from-apex). Try removing the spaces, something like `MultiPickListIndicationLevel1 = 'Blood;Cancer';`

Answer (score 1):

Where are these picklist values being saved to?

If you want them to display on edit, you will have to modify your getter method to populate the MultiPickListIndicationLevel* variable.

I.e.

```
public string MultiPickListIndicationLevel1{
    get {
        return indicatorLevel1;
    }
    set;
}
```

or, set it in your constructor

```
public YourVFController() {
    // get value of indicatorLevel1 somehow
    MultiPickListIndicationLevel1 = indicatorLevel1;
}
```

Comment: i tried setting the variable in controller it is not working

Comment: @Razu can you [edit](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/146743/edit) your post to be more specific than "not working"? That doesn't give answers much to work with

Comment: @battery.cord, updated with specific question.